# Script is running out of control

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Some strange thing is happening with my view.
I am returning Json result back to my view to display data on ajax calls.
And I am trying to display a small message if my data.length==0

**No Data available for this criteria**

Also I am using  $.blockUI (saying Please wait) and when my data.length = 0 then my page remains saying please wait... for ages and when I run this in firefox the I got message

**A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding**

### My View:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

$("#GetReport").click(function () {
    $.blockUI({
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        data: { 'manufacturer': manufacturer, 'country': country, 'category': category, 'startDate': startDate, 'endDate': endDate, 'chartType': chartType },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //setTimeout($.unblockUI, 5);
            var retailerNameArray = [];
            var clicksArray = [];
            var weekNoArray = [];
            var rowTotalArray = [];
            var weekArray = [];
            var columnTotalArray = [];
            var cumTotalArray = [];
            var weekCounterArray = [];
            var overallClickCountArray = [];
            var resellerShareArray = [];
            var retailerCount = 0;

            //we want to include total in the chart
            var weekNoArrayIncTotal = [];
            var retailerNameArrayIncTotal = [];
            var clicksArrayIncTotal = [];
            var totalWeekCounter;

            var weekNumberIncTotal = 0;
            var counter = 1;
            //if there is no data we do not want to display the graph etc

            if (data.length == 0) {

                $('#noData').show();
                $('#chartContainer').hide();
                $('#tableContainer').hide();
                $('.exportData').hide();
            }

            //we need to add one more because of total but then 0 it


            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var cumLeadrow = data[i];
                // var y = 1;
                //Only display on graph if not 0

        }
    });

});

//]]>
```

No Data available for the criteria specified

As always any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's a few syntaxc errors in the code. Could you please correct them (The ajax call is missing a `})` and the success handler is missing a `}` and your click handler is also missing `}`

Comment: @Rune Fs sorry I dint copied my whole view as it too large I will copy that

Comment: @Rune FS please see my edit

Comment: you shouldn't copy the whole view you should post a SSCCE.org. The process of narrowing down to a SSCCE often also yields the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if either `data.length - l` or  `data.length - cc` are less than 0 your script will run forever.

When you posted the full code you had a set of while loops like the one below

```
while (typeof weekCounterArray[data.length - l] == 'undefined') {
   l++
}
```

if ever `data.length - l < 0` then it will stay negative and any array indexed with a negative number yields `undefined` which will result in the loop running pratically forever (practically because it will underflow at some point and will get back to a valid range if one exist at some point)

this will happen in two different cases, The most likely being that `data.length == 0` since `l` is initialized to `1` this will result in a negative index. The other less likely scenario is when the array you are indexing has undefined values from index `0` to index `data.length-1` E.g. `[undefined,undefined,1,2,3,4]`  would result in a practically infinite loop for `data.length == 2`

Comment: can you be more clear sorry I didnt understand what do you mean by data.length-l amd data.length - cc

Comment: @AchieveSolution those are both snippets from your code see the update for more explanations

Comment: I have checked the code what you said and yes that makes sense and I am doing while only when data.length!=0  and it worked beautifully. Million thanks.